# jQuery - Checking val isn't empty and contains a specific piece of text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I've got a .js file that checks that the values of my form. I'm trying to check that the form values aren't empty, and that one of the values contains a specific piece of text (in this case, my name). If the form does hold my name, then run the rest of the script.

Where I have commented //etc etc, an AJAX script is ran that posts to a PHP file.

This is all functioning as expected, until I run the additional if statement checking the input value for my name.

```
    $('#submit').click(function(e){

            this.enabled=true;

    if ($.trim($("#name").val()) === "" || $.trim($("#topic_title").val()) === ""){
    $('#message').html('you did not fill out one of the fields').css("color", "#be4343")
            return false;

if($('#name').val().indexOf("Rich") != -1){ // without this if statement, the code runs fine.
        $('#message').html("You have entered the wrong name.");
        return false;
    }

     } else {


if($('#name, #topic_title').length && $('#name, #topic_title').val().length){

        var name = $("#name").val();
        var topic_title = $("#topic_title").val();

    }}
    // etc etc
    });
```

Question: How would I go about checking that the value of the id '#name' isn't empty, and that it contains a specific piece of text?

Thanks in advance,

Richie.

**Solution:**

I removed the additional if statement and included the following code.

```
var name = $('#name').val();
if ( name.indexOf("Rich") || $.trim($("#name").val()) === ""){
```

Comment: what is happening when you run the additional if, and how is it breaking your codee?

Comment: Step 1: Format your code readably, using consistent indentation.

Answer (score 2):

If you indent your code consistently, it's fairly clear why you have a problem:

```
$('#submit').click(function(e) {

    this.enabled = true;

    if ($.trim($("#name").val()) === "" || $.trim($("#topic_title").val()) === "") {
        $('#message').html('you did not fill out one of the fields').css("color", "#be4343")
        return false;

        if ($('#name').val().indexOf("Rich") != -1) { // Note that this is WITHIN the `if ($.trim($("#name").val()) === "" || $.trim($("#topic_title").val()) === "")` condition
            $('#message').html("You have entered the wrong name.");
            return false;
        }

    } else {


        if ($('#name, #topic_title').length && $('#name, #topic_title').val().length) {

            var name = $("#name").val();
            var topic_title = $("#topic_title").val();

        }
    }
    // etc etc
});
```

If you want it to be handled, it needs to be an `else if` for that condition instead:

```
$('#submit').click(function(e) {

    this.enabled = true;

    if ($.trim($("#name").val()) === "" || $.trim($("#topic_title").val()) === "") {
        $('#message').html('you did not fill out one of the fields').css("color", "#be4343")
        return false;

    } else if ($('#name').val().indexOf("Rich") != -1) { // without this if statement, the code runs fine.
        $('#message').html("You have entered the wrong name.");
        return false;

    } else {


        if ($('#name, #topic_title').length && $('#name, #topic_title').val().length) {

            var name = $("#name").val();
            var topic_title = $("#topic_title").val();

        }
    }
    // etc etc
});
```

(Well, as you have `return`, those could both just be `if` rather than `else if`...)

There are other problems though, for instance this expression in your final block:

```
$('#name, #topic_title').length
```

...which checks to see if either `#name` or `#topic_title` elements exist in your DOM at all (it doesn't do anything to check their values, and it doesn't require that they *both* exist, just one of them), and this:

```
$('#name, #topic_title').val().length
```

...will only check the value in `#name`, it will completely ignore the value in `#topic_title`, because when used as a getter, `val` only gets the value of the **first** element in the jQuery set. (Almost all of jQuery's functions that can be getters or setters are like that; the exception is `text` which is different from the others.)

Finally, this line:

```
this.enabled = true;
```

...is almost certainly a no-op, since the button cannot be clicked if it's not enabled, and as [lshettyl points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31905484/jquery-checking-val-isnt-empty-and-contains-a-specific-piece-of-text/31905537?noredirect=1#comment51725225_31905537), the property's name is `disabled`, not `enabled`. So `this.disabled = false;` if you're trying to enable it, or `this.disabled = true;` if you're trying to disable it.

Comment: And also, the correct form is `this.disabled = false;`

Answer (score 0):

By the look of your code, I assume you have a form that has either a `class` or an `ID` (or nothing). It'd be clever to use the form's `submit` event as opposed to `click` event of the submit button. This way you ensure that the form can also be submitted via the enter button (remember accessibility?). This is only an extension to [T.J. Crowder's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31905537/572827) answer which has lots of good points from which you can learn/improve coding.

```
//Let's say your form has an ID 'topic'
$("#topic").on("submit", function() {
    //Cache jQuery objects that would be resued, for better performance.
    var $name = $("#name"),
        $title = $("#topic_title"),
        $msg = $('#message');

    //One of the elements doesn't exist (exit)
    //1 + 1 <= 1
    if ($name.length + $title.length <= 1) {
        return;
    }

    if ($.trim($name.val()) === "" || $.trim($title.val()) === "") {

        $msg.html('you did not fill out one of the fields').css("color", "#be4343")
        return;

    } else if ($name.val().indexOf("Rich") !== -1) {

        $msg.html("You have entered the wrong name.");
        return;

    } else {
        //You do not need further checks such as length, val etc.
        //as they have already been checked above.
        var name = $name.val();
        var topic_title = $title.val();
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can make comparison to know if it's empty:

```
if($('#name, #topic_title').length && $('#name, #topic_title').val().length){

     var name = $("#name").val();   
     var topic_title = $("#topic_title").val();

    }}
    if(name=='' || name==undefined){
       //do stuff here
    }
    });
```